# Combining Southern Magician and Arcane Disciple feats - Casting Attribute

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, attributes

I have trouble understanding the details of the full scope of the Southern Magician feat in conjuction with the Arcane Disciple feat:

> **Southern Magician** [General]
>
> (...) Benefit: Once per day per two spellcaster levels, you can **cast a divine spell as an arcane spell, or vice versa**. This enables you to bypass arcane spell failure due to armor, or gain additional benefit from spell that functions differently for a divine caster instead of an arcane caster, such as true seeing or magic weapon. (...)
>
> The actual source of the spell’s power doesn’t change, nor does
> its means of preparation. You are merely weaving the strands of
> magic together in an unconventional way that makes the spell
> behave somewhat differently. *[[Emphasis mine]]*

and

> **Arcane Disciple** [General]
>
> (...)Benefit:  Add the chosen domain's spells to your class list of arcane spells. If you have arcane spellcasting ability from more than one class, you must pick which arcane spellcasting ability this feat applies to. Once chosen, this decision cannot be changed for that feat.
>
> You may learn these spells as normal for your class; however, you **use Wisdom (rather than the normal ability for your spellcasting) when determining the save DC for the spell. In addition, you must have a Wisdom score equal to 10 + the spell's level in order to prepare or cast a spell gained from this feat**. Each day, you may prepare (or cast, if you cast spells without preparation) a maximum of one of these domains spells of each level. (...) *[[Emphasis mine]]*

My questions would be:

1. Does the emphasised "cast as arcane" have an impact on casting attribute from the Arcane Disciple feat. Eg: would a divine magic missile be controlled by the divine or arcane casting attribute? And an arcane sanctuary?

Obviously I'm looking at the angle, that if the casting attribute is based on the spell being divine or arcane, would mean that - with Southern Magician & Arcane Disciple combined - you would in the end of the day just gain add additional arcane spells to your spell book thus being freed from your divine casting attribute. Granted, just for a number of times / day.

Comment: Separated from original post - https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/165304/southern-magician-feat-as-prerequisite-for-arcane-divine-casters based on Moderator comment here (https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/165304/southern-magician-feat-as-prerequisite-for-arcane-divine-casters#comment439131_165304)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Combined with the Arcane disciple feat, does it enable you to cast the obtained domain classes based on intelligence (as you cast the divine spells as arcane)?

RAW, no. Though Arcane Disciple explains its spells using Wisdom as being due to their being divine, this is an *explanation* that isn’t phrased as a *rule*. Ultimately, under the rules, as [Please stop being evil’s answer says](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/165398/4563), the spells use Wisdom because Arcane Disciple says they use Wisdom. The only way that can change is if something else says they now use something else; it isn’t “implicit” in their being divine. In short, nothing says arcane spells automatically use Intelligence—after all, for a lot of classes, they use Charisma, and in one case (the Unseelie dark hunter prestige class) there are even explicitly-arcane spells that use Wisdom. So making your Wisdom-based divine spells into arcane spells just means that they are Wisdom-based arcane spells, nothing more.

But since Arcane Disciple does explain the spells using Wisdom as being due to their being divine, feel free to ask your DM to houserule that you use Intelligence in that case. I’d probably allow it.

Answer (score 3):

## Changing the 'type' of spell does not change the attribute

Arcane Disciple does not require Wisdom because the spells are divine spells-- it requires Wisdom because it says it does.  That design choice sure seems *likely* to have been made because Wisdom is the typical divine spellcasting attribute, but there are several classes, like the Archivist, that use other stats for their divine spells, and a class, the not-complete-warrior  Dark Hunter, that gets Wisdom as an arcane casting stat.

Southern magician says the spell changes whether it counts as arcane or divine.  Since whether your domain spells are arcane or divine has nothing to do with whether you use Wisdom or your normal casting stat, that won't change your stat back to normal.